# select box by simple_form in Rails - save id, not title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I use Simple Form in Rails app for generate forms.

Schema:

```
create_table "product_materials", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "material_id"
    t.integer  "level",       default: 0
    t.integer  "value",       default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
  end
```

Model:

```
class ProductMaterial < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :material

  enum level: [:joinery, :grinding, :painting, :assembly]
end
```

View:

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, @product_material], remote: true do |f|
  => f.hidden_field :product_id, value: @product.id
  => f.input :level, collection: [t('product.joinery'), t('product.grinding'), t('product.painting'), t('product.assembly')], label: false
  => f.association :material
  => f.submit t('form.save')
```

And now is a question:
How I can in select_box show some collection of names (using I18n), but save a number of selected item (integer)?

Comment: I'm not completely sure about this one but I think you can pass an array of arrays as the `collection` option.  `f.input :level, collection: [ [ t('product.joinery'), :joinery], ... ]`. Try it out.

Comment: The reason this may work is that [`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) accepts `[[text, value]]` arrays for the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can in select_box show some collection of names (using I18n),
>   but save a number of selected item (integer)?

`ProductMaterial.levels` should return a hash like(note a plural form `levels`):

```
=> {"joinery"=>0, "grinding"=>1, "painting"=>2, "assembly"=>3}
```

You can use it, all what you need it's make an array of arrays:

```
=> ProductMaterial.levels.keys.map{ |x| t("product.#{x}") }.zip(ProductMaterial.levels.values)
#> [[t("product.joinery"), 0], [t("product.grinding"), 1], [t("product.painting"), 2], [t("product.assembly"), 3]]
```

In input:

```
=> f.input :level, collection: ProductMaterial.levels.keys.map{ |x| t("product.#{x}") }.zip(ProductMaterial.levels.values), label: false
```

[`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) have a good documentation.

Comment: Tnx for your answer, but something went wrong...  
map work correct, view render correct too,  but after submit I have error:  `ArgumentError ('1' is not a valid level)`  
if I create record with the same arguments by console all work fine

Comment: use just `ProductMaterial.levels.keys.map{ |x| t("product.#{x}") }.zip(ProductMaterial.levels.keys)` enum fields allows only `keys` and not values in this hash, so `1` is not `level` value for enum field, `painting` is valid level, it's like `enum` works in `Rails`.

Comment: woohoo!! now all work fine! 
but why `ProductMaterial.create(product_id: 21, level: 0, material_id: 44, value: 5)` in console work correct and create new record? `value` field is just an integer, and `1` or `0` must be correct arguments...